# D3.js tooltip positioning

Tags: javascript, d3.js

So I'm trying to create a tooltip on a line chart. I've done this

```
var tooltipDiv = d3.select('body')
    .append('div')
    .attr('class', 'tooltip')
    .style('opacity', 0);
```

In the mouseover function I did this-

```
tooltipDiv.transition()
    .duration(200)
    .style("opacity",0.9);
tooltipDiv.html(
        "<div class='tooltip-val'>" + d[model.get('lineTitle')] + "</div>" + 
        "<div class='tooltip-date'>" + date + "</div>"
    )
    .style("left", d3.event.pageX + "px")     
    .style("top", d3.event.pageY + "px");
```

But this makes the div appear only in the topleft and never around the point at which the mouse event happens.

Why?

Comment: Did you verify that you're getting the coordinates you're expecting?

Comment: yes i did they look close to where the object over the tooltip is

Comment: Could you post a complete example please?

Comment: Also, set the position of the `tooltipDiv` to absolute, like such: `.style("position", "absolute")`.